# Vb.net changing or blocking the header info which webbrowser control sends

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, http-headers, user-agent, vb.net-2010

How to change header of webbrowser control?

I mean not just UA i want to change remove or mask all information it may be collected on website, ip, resolution, have java, have flash so on.

Thank you for any info.

Comment: You cannot hide your IP address.

Comment: that can be done over proxy, other solutions? and how to hide language, os info and similar things? Is there solution or no other than to build own browser from scratch which wont send this info?

Comment: browser is the one who collect all info and sends it in headers right?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://awesomium.codeplex.com/ you should be able to all you want with that, depending on your ability

Comment: i have tried to include it into my app but again its same as IE browser control, not much options or way to change headers. http://analyze.privacy.net and https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes again contains all my info language, fonts, user agents, dlls etc. Do you have any example how to?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could navigate to a [proxy site](http://proxify.com/), and programmatically enter any information through it's interface, and browse anonymously? Just a thought.

Comment: i wouldn't like to rely on third party.

Comment: Well unless you setup a proxy yourself in some other country, you don't really have any options other than relying on a third party.